# Difficulty with variadic functions

Tags: go

From *An Introduction to Programming in Go*, page 91, Exercise Question no 4, Topic: Functions:

*Write a function with one variadic parameter that finds the greatest number in a list of numbers?*

So far I had written this code but it is showing errors

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func findMaximum(args ...[]int) []int {
    max := args[0]
    for _, v := range args {
        if v > []args {
            max = v
        }
    }
    return args
}

func main() {
    x := []int{
        48, 96, 86, 68,
        57, 82, 63, 70,
        37, 34, 83, 27,
        19, 97, 9, 17,
    }
    fmt.Println(findMaximum(x))
}
```

I had taken reference from this Program

(Page, 75, Question No. - 4, Topic: Arrays, Slices and Maps)

*Write a program that finds the smallest number
in this list:*

```
x := []int{
 48,96,86,68,
 57,82,63,70,
 37,34,83,27,
 19,97, 9,17,
}
```

This is the program I had written to solve this Question

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    arr := []uint{
        48, 96, 86, 68,
        57, 82, 63, 70,
        37, 34, 83, 27,
        19, 97, 9, 17,
    }

    min := arr[0] // assume first value is smallest

    for _, value := range arr {
        if value < min {
            min = value // found another value, replace previous value of min
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("The smallest value is : ", min)
}
```

This Question Program is running but the First one is not I don't know why.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too - despite its harsh title. Specifically, the errors show would be helpful. As a rule of thumb: Make it easy for others to help you, eliminate the guesswork.

Comment: Surely the book explained what variadic parameters are and how they are used before giving this task. Take another look. Hint: your function signature is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In mathematics and in computer programming, a variadic function is a
>   function of indefinite arity, i.e., one which accepts a variable
>   number of arguments.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)

Your function signature is slightly incorrect.

```
func findMaximum(args ...[]int) []int
```

This indicates that `findMaximum` takes in a variable number of `int` slices as arguments and returns an `int` slice. The problem that you're trying to solve is asking to take in a variable number of `int` arguments and return a singular `int` which is the largest in the set provided.

Calling your function would look something like this:

```
largest := findMaximum([]int{1, 2, 3}, []int{4, 5, 6}, []int{7, 8, 9})
```

In this case, `largest` would be of type `[]int` indicating that the function returned multiple `int` values in the form of a slice. This wouldn't make sense, since there should only be **one** largest value (assuming no duplicates).

You're wanting a function signature that looks like this:

```
func findMaximum(args ...int) int
```

Calling this function would look like this:

```
largest := findMaximum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

...or if you had your numbers in a slice:

```
nums := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
largest := findMaximum(nums...)
```

In this case, `largest` would be of type `int`, which is the correct return value you're looking for in this problem.

[(Go Playground)](https://play.golang.org/p/g1778ZJOSYz)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code through https://play.golang.org/ you will see a couple of syntax errors. Below is the correct version which finds max in a slice. 
As you can note you had extra `...` in the slice argument call.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func findMaximum(args []int) int {
    max := args[0]
    for _, v := range args {
        if v > max{
            max = v
        }
    }
    return max
}

func main() {
    x := []int{
        48, 96, 86, 68,
        57, 82, 63, 70,
        37, 34, 83, 27,
        19, 97, 9, 17,
    }
    fmt.Println(findMaximum(x))
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate that you had rewritten this correct code for me. Thank you.